# Web3 - Buy token by code

Tags: web3js, transactions, python, external-api, pancakeswap

i'm trying to buy $TRY token with my code. It's BSC token. The problem is when i send money to the contract i don't receive any token :/

The contract i'm trying to buy :
https://bscscan.com/token/0xc12ecee46ed65d970ee5c899fcc7ae133aff9b03

I'm coding in python using Web3 wrapper : https://pypi.org/project/web3/

```
 signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(dict(
        nonce=w3.eth.getTransactionCount(MY_WALLET),
        gasPrice=int(w3.eth.gasPrice*1.5),
        gas=200000,
        to=w3.toChecksumAddress('0xc12ecee46ed65d970ee5c899fcc7ae133aff9b03'),
        value=w3.toWei(amount, 'ether'),
        data=b'',
    ),
        'PRIVATEKEY',
    )
```

I tried with the contract address :
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xb9652d6f36d22a13a5fc877ade45d7f1c882eec80fd224c87949284793f6fe1a
Payment is OK but i don't receive any token.

I also tried with the pancake routers :
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc89b620fc08c37dec87f1daa0d79cb1a01f2f0e7b9c200e6fcaf52c66ebe5297
But i got an error "A  status code indicating if the top-level call succeeded or failed (applicable for Post BYZANTIUM blocks only). I don't understand it.

My account detail (only 4 transactions) :
https://bscscan.com/address/0x033f7eea8799696ff46293cf8d84903a6aeeab05

Do you have any idea about how i can buy or sell this token with code ?
Manually i do it with pancakeswap. There is also an ETH $TRY token with same address but i got same problem ...